# What is a name of this port? And for what purpose can it be used?

Tags: laptop

What is a name of the port below (the first port on the right)? And for what purpose can it be used?

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a "guessing-game" type question.  See http://meta.superuser.com/a/6074/23133

Comment: According to [JSanchez's](http://superuser.com/a/709749/266456) answer: its called Fireware IEEE 1394

Comment: @JasonOOO if you feel your question has been answered mark one of the given answers as accepted.

Comment: Is it still a "guessing game" when it's something not obscure, common knowledge, deeply related to basic PC hardware and easily answerable by the community? I consider this question extremely on-topic: "I have this hardware port on my laptop. What's this? What's it purpose?"

Comment: 4-pin IEEE1394 aka Firewire 400, but wasn't it be easier to take a quick look in the manual of the device that has this port, instead of asking this question?

Comment: It is indeed a guessing question when you cannot reasonably search for the question's content. @tha

Comment: @random: then how people on this planet can ask questions like this?

Comment: How would you ask this without an image? That would be the direction.

Comment: @random: I am sure if I ask it without an image, you will ask me to provide an image!

Comment: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/7647/are-hardware-port-cable-etc-visual-identification-questions-allowed-or-not

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That's a 4-conductor [Firewire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_1394) 400 connector.

Comment: oh great!!! I hope to update your answer with some detail so that reader can get some idea before opening the link that you provided.

Comment: It was more than a link answer. See, it says `that's a 4-conductor Firewire 400 connector.` I think I shall refrain from answering questions such as this, where clicking on a link might be too much work for others. Yet not providing a link to a better explanation is OK? Nitro2k01 summarized it well, but they didn't provide a link to further the user's education. Hmm..doesn't make sense. Anyway, from now on, I will only try to assist with questions where I can provide more than just a link.

Comment: @Ramhound I think the answer was fine, the answer could have no link at all and it would still answer the question fully ("What is that port"/"The port is a 4 conductor Firewire 400 connector") The link is just a nice extra external reference if the reader does not know what Firewire is and would like to learn more. Had the answer been "*It is a port for [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_1394)*" I would totally agree with you, but the answer as-is stands alone without the link.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - I agree. Perhaps its more of a border case. The author himself wanted more information.  I just feel it takes more then a single sentence to describe the port.

Answer (score 18):

It's a four pin Firewire 400 connector. It can be used with any device that supports Firewire 400, except devices that are bus powered, since the four pin variant of the connector only includes the data pins and not the power connections.

Firewire is (at least to the user) a generic serial bus interface, much like USB. Firewire has fallen out of favour to USB, but was previously popular in professional video and audio equipment, such as high-end camcorders, and audio devices.